# Is there a way to get back to while loop after fgets returns null?

Tags: c, linux

so, I have somethings like this, im creating my own shell and im trying to use fgets in order to read the commands passed from terminal, the thing is that when i press enter, so a blank space, i get a segmentation fault, i think it's due to the fact that im using fgets to read the line, so when pressed enter in blank it returns null and crash. I want to be able to press enter and get back the terminal line, is there a way of doing so with fgets?
My code looks like this:

```
int main(){ /* shell loop */

char command[COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE];
char *tokens[TOKEN_BUFFER_SIZE];

int token_Size = 0;

int pid;
int child_pid;
int status;

int flag;
int check;

int isPipe;
int output;
int input;

signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

while (1)
{

    using_history();
    customPrompt();

    token_Size = 0;
    if (fgets(command, COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) == NULL)
        continue;

    
    token_Size = parse(command, tokens, token_Size);
    if (token_Size == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }


    if (strcmp(tokens[0], "exit") == 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    if (strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0)
    {
        if ((check = chdir(tokens[1])) == -1)
        {
            perror("");
        }
        continue;
    }

    if ((child_pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("Fork:");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (child_pid == 0)
    {

        output = needs_out_redir(tokens, token_Size);
        input = needs_in_redir(tokens, token_Size);
        isPipe = needs_pipe(tokens, token_Size);

        flag = 0;

        if (output != -1)
        {
            redirect_output(tokens, output);
            tokens[output] = NULL;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (input != -1)
        {
            redirect_input(tokens, input);
            tokens[input] = NULL;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (isPipe != -1)
        {
            create_pipe(tokens, output, input, isPipe);
        }

        if (flag || isPipe == -1)
        {
            execvp(tokens[0], tokens);
            perror("Unkown Command:");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pid = wait(&status);
    }
}

return 0;
}


static int parse(char *input, char *args[], int size){
int i = 0;

input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

args[i] = strtok(input, " ");
if (!args[i])
{ // No tokens found
    return 0;
}

while (args[++i] = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    size++;
}

return size;
}
```

Could anyone please give me a hand?

To make my self clearer:

```
ivo@ivo-Surface-Pro-6:/home/ivo/Documents/SO1$
```

this is displayed, and after i press enter with no command in

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

thats what i get, i want to get back the first line.

The parse function I’m using to read line is above

--After some  I managed to fix the seg fault issue, but now I cant get the shell to recognize any of the other commands, "cd .." does, but commands like "pwd" doesnt, "exit" either, and if I type any other thing like "asd" it prints again the custom prompt

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV7oo.png)

Comment: Modify your `parse` function (which you haven't shown) to handle such input.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: If `fgets()` returns NULL, it has either encountered EOF or an error. You can find out which with `feof()` and/or `ferror()`; this is a time when using them is (can be) correct.  You can reset the stream with `clearerr()` and try again.

Comment: `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';`?  What if the input string doesn't end with a `'\n'` character?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Nothing, it does the same

Comment: And that's ***BAD*** - it rips off the last character no matter what it is, and as others have noted if the string is zero-length that line of code corrupts memory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with `fgets()`. Your `parse()` function isn't prepared for an empty line. It should check if the first `strtok()` returns `NULL`, and exit immediately.

```
static int parse( char* input, char* args[],int size){
    int i = 0;

    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0'; 

    args[i] = strtok( input, " " );
    if (!args[i]) { // No tokens found
        return 0;
    }

    while( args[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ") ){
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Then in `main()` you need to check that `token_Size` is not 0 before processing the parsed line.

```
        token_Size = parse(command, tokens, token_Size);
        if (token_Size == 0) {
            continue;
        }
```

However, you should *also* check the result of `fgets()`. Replace the line that calls `fgets()` with this:

```
    if (!fgets(command, COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)) {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But im still having the same segmentation fault, when I add the while another function, in order to execute for example 'cd', the code is:

`if (strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0)
  {
   if ((check = chdir(tokens[1])) == -1)
   {
    perror("");
   }
   continue;
  }`

Maybe I should check something for this also?

Comment: Detail: `input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';` fails (UB) when the first character read is a _null character_.   It can also drop the last character even if not `'\n'`.  `input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;` has neither of those problems.  Or just drop that line and use `" \n"` for token parsing.

Comment: Certainly the OP's `parse()` function will produce the wrong return value if the input string contains no non-space characters, but it's unclear to me why you suppose that it is responsible for their segfault.  Are you asserting that `strtok` should not be called again with a null first argument if it returned a null pointer on the previous call?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica when i type that is says that "error: too few arguments to function ‘strcspn’
  270 |  input[strcspn("\n")] = 0;"

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's what I was assuming

Comment: @IvoFerrari You need to check that `token_size > 0` when `parse()` returns.

Comment: @IvoFerrari [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435558/is-there-a-way-to-get-back-to-while-loop-after-fgets-returns-null/64435800?noredirect=1#comment113938705_64435800) amended.

Comment: Well, @Barmar, you could be right that that's the source of the OP's error, but the standard does not seem to say either way, and at least some `strtok()` implementations seem to be just fine with extra calls under the circumstances.

Comment: I assumed the segfault was happening in parse, since they didn't mention any other code. But now they mentioned code that calls `strcmp(tokens[0], "cd")`, and that's obviously the problem because it doesn't check that `tokens[0]` is non-null.

Comment: i do not think that he wants to exit the loop

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the necessary check.

Comment: @P__J__ If `fgets()` returns `null` it's either EOF or an error; most shells exit when they get EOF. However, when they get an empty input, I use `continue;` to get the next line.

Comment: I modified the code with the verification of token size but now it only stays in the loop, doesnt recognize any other command, i have just created one to exit the shell but it doesnt recognize it, it uses the same or a simillar structure to cd:
`
  token_Size = parse(command, tokens, token_Size);
  if (token_Size == 0)
  {
   continue;
  }`

Comment: @P__J__ I use continue; but i still get that seg fault :/

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar There i modified it. Hope it clarifies my issue

Answer (score 1):

The first line of parse:

```
input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
```

will crash when strlen(input) is 0, since it writes to input[-1].  Check for a 0 length string before calling parse.

Comment: For the first character to be `'\0'`, it requires that `fgets()` reads a _null character_, uncommon, but possible input.

Answer (score 0):

Add the check if `fgets` was successful or its size is zero.

```
if(!fgets(command, COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) || !command[0]) 
   continue;
```